# Can I clean up my recursive generic classes?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a trio of classes `A`, `B`, and `C` that form a hierarchy: each `A` keeps an `ObservableCollection<B>` of its children, each `B` keeps a reference to its parent `A` and an `ObservableCollection<C>` of its own children, and each `C` keeps a reference to its parent `B`.

I want to use generics to make parent/child operations cleaner. I made `Parent` an abstract class with some default child-handling behavior, and since `B` has to be both a parent and child, I made an interface `IChild`.

I want to enforce:

1. `A`'s children must be `B`s
2. `B`'s children must be `C`s
3. `B`'s parent must be an `A`
4. `C`'s parent must be a `B`

I ended up with the following recursive definitions after much finagling. This pattern ends up enforcing that the children of some class `X : Parent` must have a Parent property of type `X`, and that the parent of some class `Y : IChild` must have a Children property of type `ObservableCollection<Y>`, which is exactly what I wanted.

```
public interface IChild<P, C> where P : Parent<P, C> where C : IChild<P, C>
{
    P Parent { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Parent<P, C> where P : Parent<P, C> where C : IChild<P, C>
{
    public Parent()
    {
        Children.CollectionChanged += ChildrenChanged;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<C> Children
    {
        get;
    } = new ObservableCollection<C>();

    protected void ChildrenChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add && e.NewItems.Count > 0 && e.NewItems[0] is C child)
        {
            child.Parent = (P)this; // Unsure why I need to cast here, since this is a Parent<P, C> by definition.
        }
    }
}

public class A: Parent<A, B> {}

public class B: Parent<B, C>, IChild<A, B>
{
    public A Parent
    {
        get; set;
    }
}

public class C: IChild<B, C>
{
    public B Parent
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

Everything seems to work, but I find that the class definitions are rather clunky and are not super easy to follow. I couldn't, however, come up with any other way to achieve the constraints I wanted to enforce. Is there a cleaner way to achieve what I'm going for?

I would love to be able to do something as simple as this:

```
public interface IChild<P> where P : Parent<this>

public abstract class Parent<C> where C : IChild<this>
```

but obviously that doesn't work.